# geom_boxplot only shows flat lines for boxes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(Sample = c("TK273751", "TK273752", "TK273753", "TK273754", 
                              "TK273755", "TK273756"), 
                   Enrichment = c(21.80, 14.10, 32.00, 20.04, 10.50, 5.20), 
                   Non.enrichment = c(38.5, 29.5, 48.3, 37.6, 42.1, 8.4)) 

data_long <- tidyr::gather(data, key = "Group", value = "Percentage", -Sample) 

data_long$Percentage <- data_long$Percentage / 100 

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = Group, y = Percentage)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~Sample) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "Percent Mapped") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

I get these box plots with flat lines:

[image: result]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP's output is as expected given their input.

Answer (score 1):

There is one value for each category (enrichment vs Non.enrichment), how you expect that there should be a boxplot for singular values.

Boxplot are normally used to summarize distribution e.g.

```
test.data <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 50),
                col2 = sample(50:150, 50))

boxplot(test.data)
```

For one value, you should go for barplot.

Plus, you need to reformat your question for easier understanding. You can find a discussion here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: FYI any user can edit posts, and users with < 2000 rep get +2 rep if your edit is accepted :)